# CSS Keyframes centering on screen resize (responsive)

Tags: css-animations, keyframe

I'm new to CSS Keyframes and I've done the following code, my question is when I try to re-size my browser I want my animation to be perfectly center on the screen. Snippet is also available. Could you please help me with that.

```css
div.background {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img.animation {
    left:-300px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: mymove 10s infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
img.animation2 {
    left:-1000px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: mymove2 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: mymove2 10s infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
img.animation3 {
    left:-1000px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: mymove 10s infinite;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes mymove2 {
    0%   {left: -300px;}
    25%  {left:-300px;}
    30%   {left: 40%;}
    31%  {left: 39%;}
    32% {left: 40%;}
    33%  {left: 39%;}
    34% {left: 40%;}
    70% {left: 40%;}
    75%  {left: 100%; opacity: 1}
    100% {left: 100%; opacity: 0}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove2 {
    0%   {left: -300px;}
    25%  {left:-300px;}
    30%   {left: 40%;}
    31%  {left: 39%;}
    32% {left: 40%;}
    33%  {left: 39%;}
    34% {left: 40%;}
    60% {left: 40%;}
    65%  {left: 100%; opacity: 1}
    100% {left: 100%; opacity: 0}
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {left: -300px;}
    5%   {left: 40%;}
    95%  {left: 40%; opacity: 1}
    100% {left: 100%; opacity: 0}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {left: -300px;}
    5%   {left: 40%;}
    95%  {left: 40%; opacity: 1}
    100% {left: 100%; opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class="background"><img class="animation" src="http://i.imgur.com/TdeyRAx.png" /><img class="animation2" src="http://i.imgur.com/yGkcaAz.png" /><img class="animation3" src="http://i.imgur.com/fSUlLle.png" /></div>
```

Comment: use bootstrap classes